# On a cluster using HDI 3.6, Spark always uses the old 1.6.3 version

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight

I have an *HDInsight* cluster running 3.6, which according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-component-versioning) bundles Spark 2.1.0 only.

Apparently Livy hasn't been integrated with this version and trying to *curl* Livy (like the Azure tutorial documentation for Spark jobs suggests) results in a `HTTP 502 BAD GATEWAY` response - so I'm trying to submit a spark job manually.

However, when I ssh into the master node and use `spark-submit` I noticed immediately that the wrapper script prints the following:

`SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 1, using spark1`

So I assumed that setting SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 would force it to run spark2, and the wrapper does detect this and prints it as it should. But the version of spark hasn't actually changed. I got a binary incompatible error (cryptic as ever with Scala - something about a `funcArrow`).

I had a look at the `spark-wrapper.sh` file and found where it handles different versions of spark:

```
else
    echo -e "SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to ${SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION}, using Spark${SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION}" 1>&2
    SCRIPT="/usr/hdp/current/spark${SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION}-client/bin/${FILE}"
fi
```

So, I launched the `spark-shell` executable inside `/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client` and it immediately prints the following:

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.3
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.10.5 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
```

Spark 2.1.0 uses Scala 2.11 - 2.10 would show a deprecation warning - so HDInsight is definitely using Spark 1.x

Have I missed something or this a known issue?

Additional information:
I created this cluster with the powershell cmdlets - but the cluster is definitely `3.6`.

Comment: i suppose you should raise it with support, i don;t think people here could help you with that

Comment: @4c74356b41 Probably will in 10 minutes or so, just wanted to know if this was a known issue or something

Comment: I don't work with that, so can't help you sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that because I was provisioning the cluster with the powershell azure cmdlets I couldn't specify the type of cluster I needed (not as far as I could tell, anyway). I've since taken the "faulty" one down, but I know I didn't receive any errors when I was creating it with the version set to 3.6. It seems HDInsight 3.6 doesn't 'necessarily' come with Spark2.

In short, provisioning is far better with the templating system from ARM (Azure Resource Manager). Doing it this way instantly got me to a prompt that had Spark2 as the default. Looking at the template it states quite clearly that the type of cluster is `SPARK2`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like HDI 3.6 cluster. Or something is wrong with the instance.
Can you check the version? Either check in Azure portal or in ssh session type: `ls /usr/hdp`. This command will print version folder of the actual bits. It should display: 2.6.0.10-29 or similar for 3.6 based cluster.